# Does blank final field apply to local variables?

Tags: java

[Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) for java 8 says

> A blank final is a final variable whose declaration lacks an initializer.

Does this mean that blank final fields are only for instance and class variables not for local variable as initializers are only for instance and class variables?

Comment: I don't quite get the question. A final var on instance level can only be initialized directly or within the constructor. A final var within a method can only be initialized directly.

Comment: You  can have local variables with initializers. For examaple, 'int i = 0;'

Comment: @m02ph3u5 there is a another concept of initializer blocks: instance variable initializers and static initializers

Comment: @NomadMaker ya thats what I am asking that whether the term initializer here used in general sense i.e. for any value or for initializer blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that blank final fields are only for instance and class variables not for local variable as initializers are only for instance and class variables?

Since *initializers* are NOT only for instance and class variables, the answer is No.

An initializer can be a part of a local variable declaration.  For example

```
public void method() {
    int i = 0;    // this declaration has an initializer
    ...
}
```

> I am asking that whether the term initializer here used in general sense i.e. for any value or for initializer blocks.

In the context that you are referring to, No.  It is specifically referring to an initializer that is *part* of a declaration.  It says:

> " ... a final variable **whose declaration** lacks an initializer."

Assuming that the initializer occurs later<sup>1</sup>(e.g. in an instance or static initializer block, or later in the same or a nested method block), then this is a *blank final*.

If it is also a field, then it is a *blank final field*.

---

Finally, the following program demonstrates that a local variable can be *blank final*:

```
public class Test {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        final int i;    // blank final
        i = 0;  
        System.out.println(i);
    } 
}
```

This compiles and runs on Java 11, and *should* compile and run on all (compliant) implementations of all versions of Java.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, the JLS doesn't expressly forbids a blank final with no initialization at all.  However, there must be an initialization before you use the variable, so such a declaration would be pointless.  A compiler is likely to warn you about unused variables.</sup>

Comment: The reasoning is wrong but the conclusion is true: A final local must be initialized at declaration.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-A final local NEED NOT necessarily be initialized at declaration. It can be initialized later also as also shown by Stephen C.